# Python Selenium code is not able to double click on a webelement when multiple tests are run together but works when tests are run individually

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Posting the code snippet

```
for abc in self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                            "//div[@class='ag-body-viewport']//div[starts-with(@class,'ag-row')]"):
                        flag = False
                        for xyz in abc.find_elements_by_tag_name("div"):
                            attr = xyz.get_attribute("colid")
                            if attr == "moduleName":
                                module_name = cluster_module.text[:-3]

                                # Check in the module given in input file is found on UI
                                if module_name == input_module:
                                    logger.warning("Module {} found.....".format(input_module))
                                    flag = True
                                    logger.warning("Flag value {}".format(flag))
                            elif attr == "inventoryTarget":
                                if flag:

                                    time.sleep(15)

                                    self.actions.double_click(xyz)\
                                            .send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a").send_keys(Keys.DELETE)\
                                            .send_keys(1000).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

please note i have a suite with multiple test cases and each test case calls this function and it works for first testcase but fails after that for subsequent testcases

Comment: so what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the flag is not being set to `true` on consecutive runs. You should check the module names in your if statement:

```
if module_name == input_module
```

I do not know what those 'modules' are, but it seems like this condition is not met.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Appium Studio. It has simple commands which can be exported / directly coded in multiple languages. For double click it would be `self.client.click("NATIVE", "your-xpath-here", 0, 2)`
The last parameter is the click count. Set it to 1 for single click. You can find [here](https://experitest.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TDB/pages/2727080/SeeTestAutomation+-+Click) the detailed documentation.